# std::map default value for enums

Tags: c++, enums, initialization

Let's say we have:

```
enum X {
  X1,
  X2,
  X3
};

int func() {
  std::map<int, X> abc;
  ...
}
```

Assume 0 is the key that is not in the container.

I know abc[0] needs to value-initialize the X object.

Here are the questions:

(1) Will the initialization always be zero-initialization for enumerations? namely abc[0] is always initialized as the enumerator corresponding to 0?

(2) What if we have

```
enum X {
  X1 = 1,
...
```

What will abc[0] be?

Comment: Zero is a valid value for X, even if it doesn't have a corresponding enumerator.

Comment: Have you run the program and print out the values?

Comment: @Brett His point was "what is the default value if you DONT set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the initialization always be zero-initialization for enumerations? namely `abc[0]` is always initialized as the enumerator corresponding to `0`?

Yes.

> What if we have
>
> ```
> enum X {
>    X1 = 1,
>    ...
> ```
>
> What will `abc[0]` be?

It will be `0`.

Working program (also can be seen at http://ideone.com/RVOfT6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

enum X {
  X1,
  X2,
  X3
};

int main()
{
   X x = {};
   std::map<int, X> abc;
   std::cout << x << std::endl;
   std::cout << abc[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
```

Comment: @Brett, the `operator[]` function of `std::map` will add a value-initialized element to the map if there is no element corresponding to the key.

Comment: When you query a map with key if it is not there it will create a node in map . So you will get value zero for abc[0]. If you check size of map before you call abc[0], it will be zero. After you query its size will be 1

Comment: @Brett: It exists ! Have a look at `map::operator[]`. A call to this function is equivalent to:
`(*((this->insert(make_pair(k,mapped_type()))).first)).second`

Comment: Sorry, I temporarily forgot about insertion with the `[]` operator.

Comment: Operator[] creating a node in map not defaulted with key value as <0,0>